# In Win32 C++, how to WaitForSingleObject and Detect Ctrl-C at the same time?

Tags: c++, winapi

In Win32 C++, How to WaitForSingleObject and Detect Ctrl-C at the same time?

I tried the following console application by compiling it in the Code::Blocks C++ compiler for windows.

Then, I tried pressing Control-C many times while running... it basically doesn't call the control-c handler while the main thread is in "WaitForSingleObject".

Is there a way to fix this?

Eventually, I want my Control-C handler to  kill the secondary thread using TerminateThread and return control to mainthread breaking WaitForSingleObject... But, because of the wait the second thread is written i can't change any of the code...

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

BOOL  WINAPI fun1(DWORD id);
DWORD WINAPI fun2(void*);

atomic<DWORD> threadid {0};

int main()
{
    DWORD threadid1;
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(fun1, TRUE);

    HANDLE H1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, fun2, 0, 0, &threadid1);

    threadid = threadid1;

    WaitForSingleObject(H1, INFINITE);
    return 0;
}

BOOL WINAPI fun1(DWORD id)
{
    Beep(750, 300);
    printf("CtrlHandler:(%ld)\n", id);
    
    if (threadid != 0) {
        HANDLE H2 = OpenThread(THREAD_TERMINATE, FALSE, threadid);
        if (H2) {
            //TerminateThread(H2, 0);
            //threadid = 0;
            CloseHandle(H2);

        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}

DWORD WINAPI fun2(void*)
{
    // This thread will eventually do some work... 
    //   and I don't want to rewrite this code...
    //   to check for a flag from another thread...
    int count = 0;
    while(1) {
        printf("count: %d\n", count);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Trying to reproduce your problem here.  Where is the `atomics` class defined?  Did you mean `std::atomic` or something?  Also did you mean `std::cout` instead of `cout`?

Comment: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/atomic/  ... sorry i was editing the code at the time...

Comment: "...because of the wait..." -- do you mean "...because of the way..."?

Comment: To synchronize threads, you can use events, you can't do everything from outside the thread. So define an event (CreateEvent) and wait for it in the thread (or check for it regularly, etc.). When ctrl-c is pressed, set the event, the thread will then stop and your WaitForSingleObject will continue

Comment: That might work... if I wait on both the thread and the event?

Comment: Terminating a thread with TerminateThread is a bad idea. It'll seem to work 99% of the time and corrupt your process 1% of the time.

Comment: The thread must wait for the event of check it somehow then exit when it's set

Comment: I'm ok with the risk of using TerminateThread... its better than nothing...

Comment: Note that `atomics` and `atomic` are different identifiers, so you code still doesn't compile.

Comment: sorry... if you look at the revision history... the first version works... I was just trying to ask a bigger question without having my compiler on my computer...

Comment: *"I'm ok with the risk of using TerminateThread"* - The only reason one could possibly make a statement like this is if they haven't fully understood the consequences. [Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150814-00/?p=91811) is a bit more information. Also make sure to read the documentation for [`CreateThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) **in full**. The TL;DR is: Don't use `CreateThread` here.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your code slightly and it seems like the Ctrl+C handler is running when expected (even though it doesn't do anything particularly useful).  When I type Ctrl+C, I see that `fun1` can run multiple times while the main thread is running `WaitForSingleObject`.

Your original code for `fun1` was beeping before printing, and it wasn't flushing the `stdout` buffer, so maybe you thought the code wasn't actually running or that it was getting delayed.

Note that I am just answering questions you asked about detecting Ctrl+C while waiting for an object; I'm not attempting to help you do anything useful in your Ctrl+C handler.

Here is the cleaned-up version of your code that I used for testing:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<DWORD> threadid {0};

BOOL WINAPI fun1(DWORD id) {
  printf("fun1: %ld\n", id);
  fflush(stdout);
  Beep(750, 100);

  // This doesn't do anything useful; can be removed.
  if (threadid != 0) {
    HANDLE H2 = OpenThread(THREAD_TERMINATE, FALSE, threadid);
    if (H2) { CloseHandle(H2); }
  }

  return 1;
}

DWORD WINAPI fun2(void *) {
  unsigned int count = 0;
  while(1) {
    count++;
    printf("count: %d\n", count);
    fflush(stdout);
    Sleep(4000);
  }
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  SetConsoleCtrlHandler(fun1, TRUE);

  DWORD threadid1;
  HANDLE H1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, fun2, 0, 0, &threadid1);
  threadid = threadid1;

  printf("Waiting for single oblect.\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  WaitForSingleObject(H1, INFINITE);
  printf("Done waiting for single oblect.\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```cpp
Hello world!
Waiting for single oblect.
count: 1
count: 2
fun1: 0
fun1: 0
fun1: 0
fun1: 0
fun1: 0
fun1: 0
fun1: 0
fun1: 0
fun1: 0
count: 3
count: 4
```

I compiled the code in MSYS2, targeting 64-bit Windows, with this command:

```
g++ -std=gnu++20 -Wall -Wextra test.cpp
```

Comment: I found out that  if you run a console app from the code::blocks GUI... then control-C doesn't work... but if you run it from the console without the code::BLocks Gui then it works...

Comment: This code is pretty useless. The console handler is just opening a handle to the thread and then closing it, it does nothing with that handle. Opening a handle with termination rights does not actual terminate anything. And the thread itself is not doing anything to look for any terminations signal.

Comment: What is this code supposed to accomplish? `CloseHandle( OpenThread( ... ) );` is a very verbose way of saying: Please, dear OS, do waste **loads** of cycles, but make sure to not have any side effect.

Comment: I just took the OP's code and made sure the Ctrl+C handler could run promptly, which is what the question is about.  I make no claims about anything else in the code.

Comment: *"Eventually, I want my Control-C handler to kill the secondary thread"* - Did you miss that part of the question? That's odd, cause [others haven't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70317747/1889329).

Comment: That's just a side comment the OP made about their ultimate goal, but this question is just about getting the Ctrl+C handler to work, and I successfully answered the question.  Look at where the question marks are positioned.  I think I'm done arguing with third parties.

Comment: I'm confused as to how exactly this proposed answer were to address the *"ultimate goal"*, seeing that it doesn't change even one bit of the original code. There's nothing useful here, and the fact that this proposed answer introduces the code as not useful doesn't change that. None of the real issues are being addressed, but [you know that already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316439/in-win32-c-how-to-waitforsingleobject-and-detect-ctrl-c-at-the-same-time/70316915#comment124301847_70316915).

Answer (score 1):

A `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()` handler gets run by the OS in its own thread. This is stated as much in the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine

> An application-defined function used with the `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` function. A console process uses this function to handle control signals received by the process. **When the signal is received, the system creates a new thread in the process to execute the function.**

You need to have that signal thread notify your worker thread to terminate itself, you can't (safely) just terminate the thread directly (ie, DO NOT use `TerminateThread()`).

Try this:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

BOOL  WINAPI fun1(DWORD);
DWORD WINAPI fun2(void*);

atomic<bool> exitThread {false};

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(fun1, TRUE);

    HANDLE H1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, fun2, 0, 0, NULL);
    if (H1)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(H1, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(H1);
    }

    return 0;
}

BOOL WINAPI fun1(DWORD id)
{
    Beep(750, 300);
    printf("CtrlHandler:(%lu)\n", id);
    exitThread = true;
    return TRUE;
}

DWORD WINAPI fun2(void*)
{
    // This thread will eventually do some work...
    int count = 0;
    while (!static_cast<bool>(exitThread)) {
        printf("count: %d\n", count++);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, do note that creating a thread just to wait on it is a waste of a thread. You may as well just do your work in `main()` directly instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

BOOL  WINAPI fun1(DWORD);

atomic<bool> exitApp {false};

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(fun1, TRUE);

    // This will eventually do some work...
    int count = 0;
    while (!static_cast<bool>(exitApp)) {
        printf("count: %d\n", count++);
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}

BOOL WINAPI fun1(DWORD id)
{
    Beep(750, 300);
    printf("CtrlHandler:(%lu)\n", id);
    exitApp = true;
    return TRUE;
}
```